# Can I set a different preferred language per site?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, language

Is there a way to change the preferred language in the browser (Firefox and/or Chrome) based on the visited site?

Most of the time I want websites to be displayed in English, but when I visit a French site that has an English version, it displays the English version, even though I'd prefer to see it in French (since I'm French).

Is there an extension that would let me control that setting on a per-site basis?

Comment: Not an option for per-site config, but isn't `about:preferences#content` -> `Languages` enough in Firefox? You can have French as first choice, and English as the second choice. That way all sites with French version available will give you French version (unless you want French version only for some sites, then you'll need an extension)

Comment: @jakub.g, no, it's not enough. I don't want to have French as the first choice, because any site that has a French version will be displayed in French, which I don't want. I really want it to be on a per-site basis.

Comment: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/locale-switcher/kngfjpghaokedippaapkfihdlmmlafcc for Chrome

Answer (score 10):

On Firefox, you can use the lightweight [Quick Accept-Language Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/quick-accept-language-switc/) extension and change the locale every time you access that site. You need to do that manually but that's the easiest and safest way I've found to do that today. There was another extension ([Quick Locale Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/quick-locale-switcher/)) that did remember site-specific locale settings, but users have reported that it doesn't work anymore.

You can also look up an extension that lets you modify HTTP headers for specific sites, and use it to change just the `Accept-Language` parameter. [Requestly for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) seems to be a good choice, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: But I found an extension ([Modify Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/)) that I could probably modify to do what I want

Comment: I didn't leave a link to it because it was last updated years ago. You shouldn't get used to old Firefox extensions because they are all going to stop working with the upcoming changes: https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/08/21/the-future-of-developing-firefox-add-ons/

Comment: For Firefox : https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/accept-language-per-site/

Comment: The addon “*Quick Locale Switcher*” has been removed from AMO.

Answer (score 0):

[Locale Switcher](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/locale-switcher/kngfjpghaokedippaapkfihdlmmlafcc) extension for Chrome :)